# How to assign JSON elements to a 2D array while in a Loop

Tags: arrays, json, 2d

I'm trying to assign two items (user ID, amount) at the same level in a JSON object into a 2D array for each user ID in the JSON object (assume this object has 10 user IDs so 2D array should have 10 rows with User ID as column 0 and Amount as column 1):

```
JSON
    {"page":"1",
     "per_page":10,
     "total":100,
     "total_pages":10,
     "data":[{"id":1,
              "userId":1,
              "userName":"Jim Silver", 
              "timestamp":16425382171,
              "txnType":"debit",
              "amount":"$1,000.07",
              "location":{"id":2,
                          "address":"654, Somewhere, Some Street", 
                          "city":"Some City",
                          "zipCode":12345},
                          "ip":"202.210.105.105"},
          {"id":2," ...}
```

The result should be (amount converted to integer and Math.Floor applied):

```
[1, 1000] // User ID = 1, corresponding amount = 1000
[2, 2000] // User ID = 2, ...
[3, 3000]
[4, 4000]
...
```

I modeled my JSON with three classes depicting the three levels in the JSON object.

I've declared a 2D array:
`int[,] userTxnsArr = new int[1, model.data.Count];` (10 rows, 2 columns)

Now loop through the deserialized JSON object in model:

```
for (int datum = 0; datum < model.data.Count; datum++)
{
    userID = model.data[datum].id;
    userAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(decimal.Parse(model.data[datum].amount, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)));
    userTxnsArr = new int[,] { { userID, userAmount } };
}
```

But I'm only getting the last JSON record in the 2D array (so only one row of data). How do I assign each JSON record into each row of the 2D array? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm feeling lacking infos about this, so I'll infer something here or there.

I'm assuming that:

- You have all information in your `"page": "1"`
- The language you're using can be javascript
- If this is not the language you want, the algorithm will be very similar due to language nature

I took the liberty of create some variables to easify some things, then... when I say `jsonData`, well... its your JSON data, no miracles here.

I'd tested it using nodejs just to do not see the JSON, but it'll work in modern browsers as well (assigning directly the JSON data)

```js
// Imagine your shining-beautiful JSON here
const jsonData = require('./data.json');

// This is your "JSON page 1" data field (array of things)
const elements = jsonData.data;

// Write your helper to convert the "amount" string into something you need
function convertAmount(rawAmount) {
        // Your amount parser should come here (currency string -> the int you want)
        // I'm just returning directly, you may change it to use
        return rawAmount;
}

// This.... is the 2D Array that you want (quite obvious variable name)
const the2DArrayYouWant = elements.map(element => [
        element['userId'],
        convertAmount(element['amount'])
]);


console.log(the2DArrayYouWant);
```

In the code above here, the `the2DArrayYouWant` is an Array of Arrays, now you can iterate and... maybe do a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) or something.

The `console.log` at the end should show you something like this:

```
[
  [ 1, '$1,000.07' ],
  [ 42, '$1,135.25' ],
  [ 156, '$9,040.00' ],
  ...
]
```

---

Note: If you're stucking to understand the `element => ([ ... ])` code pieces, they are just functions without names.

```js
// A function that will run some received function
function runThisFunction( receivedFunction ) {
  const numberTen = 10;

  return receivedFunction( numberTen );
}


// Writing this
function doubleValue(value) {
  return value * 2;
}

runThisFunction( doubleValue ); // 20


// Is the same thing as writing this
runThisFunction( (value) => { 
  return value * 2;
});


// That is the same thing as writing this
runThisFunction( value =>  value * 2 );
```

Hope this helps, have fun!

Comment: Yes, all information is in Page 1 but there can be more than 1 page (I don't think that should matter for this problem). Should have mentioned - this is in C#. Thanks.