# How to Do GroupBy with List<List<int>> and Return List<List<int>> in C#?

Tags: c#, json, list, group-by

This is a follow on to a previous question ([How to assign JSON elements to a 2D array while in a Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60943491/how-to-assign-json-elements-to-a-2d-array-while-in-a-loop)) I asked. My data starts in a JSON object:

```
JSON
    {"page":"1",
     "per_page":10,
     "total":100,
     "total_pages":10,
     "data":[{"id":1,
              "userId":1,
              "userName":"Jim Silver", 
              "timestamp":16425382171,
              "txnType":"debit",
              "amount":"$1,000.07",
              "location":{"id":2,
                          "address":"654, Somewhere, Some Street", 
                          "city":"Some City",
                          "zipCode":12345},
                          "ip":"202.210.105.105"},
             {"id":2," ...}
             {"id":3," ...}
              ...
             {"id":n," ...}]
```

I need to get the user ID and amount into a `List<List<int>>` which I've done here:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TxnResponse>(rawJSON);
var elements = model.data;

List<List<int>> userTxns = new List<List<int>>(elements.Count);
List<int> record = null;

int userID = 0;
int userAmount = 0;

for (int row = 0; row < elements.Count; row++)
{
    userID = elements[row].userId;
    userAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(decimal.Parse(model.data[row].amount, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)));

    record = new List<int>();
    record.Add(userID);
    record.Add(userAmount);

    userTxns.Add(record);
}

return userTxns.GroupBy();
```

The result should look like this when printed to screen (`Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", list.Select(x => String.Join(" ", x))));`):

`1 1000
2 2000
3 3000
4 4000`

Without the Group By, if the JSON object has 10 data items, I have 10 user ID, amount records. I've tried `return userTxns.GroupBy(userID);` and `return userTxns.GroupBy(u => userID);` but get "the type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage..." or "Cannot implicitly convert type...".

Model:

```
  public class TxnResponse
    {
        public string page { get; set; }
        public int per_page { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
        public int total_pages { get; set; }
        public List<data> data { get; set; }
    }


    public class data
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int userId { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public object timestamp { get; set; }
        public string txnType { get; set; }
        public string amount { get; set; }
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public string ip { get; set; }
    }
public class Location
    {
        public int LocationID { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
    }
```

How do I do GroupBy on user ID? Thank you.

Comment: What is the definition of your `TxnResponse` class?

Comment: @BrianRogers - I tried to get my comment above to format as code ... I appreciate your interest; if you copy and paste the above text into Notepad and perform some formatting, you'll see the structure. I appreciate what you can offer. Thanks.

Comment: @BrianRogers - I was able to past my models into my question. Again, appreciate yours or anyone who can provide guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for posting your model.  I'm not sure I completely understand your example.  Are you trying to *sum* the amounts for each user ID?  For example if the original data had amounts 100 and 200 for user 1 and amounts 400 and 500 for user 2, is your expected output a 2D list of ints like `[ [ 1, 300 ], [ 2, 900 ] ]`?  Or do you really mean group, where you still want to see all the individual amounts for each user?

Comment: Yes, sum the amounts for each user ID for each location ID as in `[ [ 1, 300 ], [ 2, 900 ], ... ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works ...

```
return userTxns.GroupBy(u => u[0], (key, values) => new List<int>
{
    key,
    values.Select(l => l[1]).Sum()
}).OrderBy(u => u[0]).ToList();
```

but there are 16 pages of data and my REST call only returns the first page ... I'll post a follow-on question.